# How to pass the dbContext to ApplicationSignInManager in aspnet identity 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, owin

I have implemented the following code:

```
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, long>
    {
        public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
            : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationSignInManager Create<TContext>(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
            where TContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
        {
            var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole, long, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>(context.Get<TContext>()));
            return new ApplicationSignInManager(manager, context.Authentication);
        }
    }
```

It compiles OK in the project. However when I then try to add it to my statup.cs as below I get errors.

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create<MyContext>);
```

I have done the exact same for UserManager and it is fine - no issues at all. But ApplicationSignInManager won't play ball. The errors I get are

Error   19  'Owin.IAppBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'CreatePerOwinContext' and the best extension method overload 'Owin.AppBuilderExtensions.CreatePerOwinContext(Owin.IAppBuilder, System.Func)' has some invalid arguments

Error   20  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Func'   \startup.auth.cs

If you need any extra information please ask, I've been stuck for a week on this! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Type parameter of your static `Create<T>` method is causing this issue, `CreatePerOwinContext` can't map your method as method group.

You may try using a lambda expression instead:

```cs
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>((options, context) => ApplicationSignInManager.Create<MyContext>(options, context));
```